# merge three web application of different region in single code base

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, architecture, frameworks

We have a Web application for three different region and we have three separate code bases,three DB,but code base is copy of one another it is same .it was done initially- whenever a new region launched we copied code from  one region and done some region specific changes and added new DB and launched .This was done to deliver region specific functionality ― like for USA region- page will contain more field then UK region and so on.

Now we want to merge everything and make it a single application ― with a single code base. The application will then let the users to select the region (using a drop down) at the time of login and  content will open specific to the region.

So I need help in designing this application. Please, suggest how to proceed and what should be design patterns or framework and the right approach for such development.
**Current structure of application**
It is a client service architecture. in front end we are using JSF and And SOAP Client and Backend SOAP Service,
it is like `USER Request->JSF Config->SOAP Client ->SOAP Service->DAO`. 
1.there is a WebEAR-we are using JSF and JAX-WS(SOAP Client)
2.there is ServiceEAR - we are using SOAP service(JAX-WS).
3.there is DAOEAR-we are using JPA
**Architecture** u`ser request->WeBEAR(JSFC config->Service Proxy)-> EserviceEAR(Service Biz Service)`

**I have thought of a solution**
At the time of login i will get the location and save it in session and  for  every request from client(WebEAR) to Service(EserviceEAR) i will pass the location and based on location i will fetch data from DB and will show the data specific to region.
please suggest some standard framework/architecture for this.

Comment: Does the proposed solution meet security requirements?  If the user selects the incorrect region (intentionally or accidentally), could the user see  more info than allowed?

Comment: @AndrewS that is being handled,here i want that how to design the application so that i don't need to pass the location with every service call.